# SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP with AdvancedCache:entrySet in a DIST_SYNC Infinispan cache

Tags: java, infinispan

just to clear up my confusion... The [tutorial for distributed caches](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/12.1.x/distributed/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/distributed/InfinispanDistributed.java) for infinispan uses the following code in the 12.x branch:

```
// Display the current cache contents for this node
cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(Flag.SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP).entrySet()
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

But isn't that wrong for the contents of "this node"? The documentation for `SKIP_REMOTE_LOOKUP` only mentions that it applies to those four methods:

- `get`
- `put`
- `remove`
- `containsKey`

Also in my test, the code above always printed out the whole cache contents, not just the local node's contents. Only switching it from `entrySet` to a manual `get` did the trick here.

Am I missing something or is this a "bug" in the tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

looks like a bug in the tutorial. The correct flag should be `Flag.CACHE_MODE_LOCAL`

Comment: You are correct, this flag actually works with entrySet - but also only if you set `builder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC).hash().numOwners(1)`, because otherwise the default for `numOwners` is `2`, which leads to both caches having the same content.

Comment: numOwner sets how many copies of your data you want. If you have a 2 node cluster with numOwner==2, then both nodes contain the same data.

Comment: Yep, and since 2 is the default, that makes that tutorial very confusing for newbies like me, because when you run two instances, CACHE_MODE_LOCAL would work, but still show no difference between the local and the complete cache ;-) And since these are supposed to be simple tutorials, I would actually suggest making them more clear to actually demonstrate what they should.